# Create a table from html.join attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a table from this code..
but i'm at stuck how to slice the data so i can put html tag  and  there..

```
var d = []; $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#geta').click(getData);
    $('#dispa').click(displayData); });

function getData(e, n) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Default.aspx'
                , cache: false
                , context: document.body
                , dataType: 'script'
    }).done(function(msg) {
        $('#dataArea').html(msg);        
    }); }

function displayData(e, n) {
    $('#displayArea').html(d.join(''); }
```

the data is

```
d =[['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
```

so far.. with that code,
i only manage to get

```
a,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,da,b,c,d
```

and what i want is

```
-------------
=============
a | b | c | d
-------------
=============
a | b | c | d
-------------
=============
a | b | c | d
-------------
=============
a | b | c | d
-------------
=============
```

it's quite hard to make a table layout here..

Comment: Are you looking for this: `d.forEach(function (e) { console.log(e.join(',')); });`

Comment: i dont really understand what to do,
all i need is to put tr td beside each array number
but i can't to understand how..@_@

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var d = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']];

var trtd = d.map(function (e) {          // map each array of array
    return '<tr>' + e.map(function (x) { // map each values of array
        return '<td>' + x + '</td>';
    }) + '</tr>';
});

$('#displayArea').html(trtd);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzX3R/)